# Arrangement of logic gates on an IC?

Tags: binary, logic, gpu, cpu, hardware

I'm just curious how data is physically transferred through logic gates. For example, does the pixel on my monitor that is 684 pixels down and 327 pixels to the right have a specific set or path of transistors in the GPU that only care about populating that pixel with the correct color? Or is it more random?

Comment: also, are transistor functions fixed? i.e. would a transistor used for an input to an AND logic gate always be an input to that logic gate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cell library en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_cell that is used when building a chip for a particular foundry, kind of like an instruction set used when compiling. the machine code for arm is different from x86 but the same code can be compiled for either (if you have a compiler for that language for each of course). So there is a list of standard functions (and, or, etc plus more complicated ones) that you compile your verilog/vhdl for. A particular cell is hardwired. There is an intimate relationship between the cell library and the foundry and the process used (28nm, 22nm, 14nm, etc).  Basically you need to construct the chip one thin layer at a time using a photographic like process, the specific semiconductors and other factors for a specific piece of equipment may vary from some other, so the 28nm technology may be different than 14nm so you may need to construct an AND gate differently thus a different cell library.  And that doesnt necessarily mean there is only one AND gate cell for a particular process at a particular foundry, it is possible that more than one has been developed.

as far has how pixels and video works, there is a memory somewhere, generally on the video card itself. Depending on the screen size, number of colors, etc that memory can be organized differently. Also there may be multiple frames used to avoid flicker and provide a higher frame rate. so you might have one screens image at address 0x000000 in this memory the video card will extract the pixel data starting at this address, while software is generating the next frame at say 0x100000.

then when it is time to switch frames based on the frame rate the logic may switch to displaying the image using 0x100000 while software modifies 0x000000.  So for a particular video mode the first three bytes in the memory at some known offset could be the pixel data for the 0,0 coordinate pixel then the next three for 1,0, and so on.  For a number like 684 they could start the second line at offset 684*3, but they might start the second at 0x400.

Whatever, for a particular mode, the OFFSET in a frame of video memory will be the same for a particular pixel so long as the mode settings dont change.  The video card due to the rules of the interface used (vga, hdmi, or interfaces specific to a phone lcd for example) has logic that reads that memory and generates the right pulses or analog level signal for each pixel.